# Improving copy activities performance on Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in ADF to copy 18 tables from source to destination. 
Noticed that the copy performance on ADF is taking too long, like 12 hours. But when we performed the same using SSIS it's took only like 2 hours. I noticed the copy activity is static when it is almost at completion. Does anyone faces the same issue?

[image: Image here]

Comment: You may want to ask this question over at Server Fault as Stackoverflow is answering questions directly connected to coding.

Comment: Can you add some information like, datasource, destination, integration runtime ?

Comment: @SaugetCharles-Henri I am not sure what kind of info on datasource & destination that i could provide, but for integration runtime is as below : 

Name : AutoResolveIntegrationRunTime,
Type : Azure,
Sub-type : Public,
Region : Auto Resolve,
Status : Running

Thanks!

Comment: @MoT, What is your Data Source type and Destination Type ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the performance tuning guide.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance